# Why can not use map stream in Map object in dart languaje?

Tags: dart, stream

By example has this code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TableContent {

  static Table render(BuildContext context, Map<String, String> rows) {
    return Table(
      border: const TableBorder(bottom: BorderSide(), horizontalInside: BorderSide()),
      children: rows.map((title, message) => TableRow(
        children: [
          Text(
            title,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium
          ),
          Text(message)
        ]
      ))
    );
  }
}
```

But says:

> The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'. (Documentation)

The map stream can not mutate type of return values like as a list. It is an error?

Answer (score 1):

This solution is half cooked. You can tweak it a bit to reach the correct output.

```dart
class TableContent {
  static Table render(BuildContext context, Map<String, String> rows) {
    return Table(
        border: const TableBorder(bottom: BorderSide(), horizontalInside: BorderSide()),
        children: rows.entries.map((entry) {
          return TableRow(children: [Text(entry['title'], style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium), Text(entry['message'])]);
        }).toList());
  }
}
```

The issue is related to the type differences between what `children:` of table needs (a list) and what the `.map()` function returns which is (a Map)